# MySQL import row count inconsistent on same file and DB

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I am trying to load a +75mb csv file with 650k+ rows into a MySQL server on Centos Linux. This is just one example. I've also tried the same with 350mb file and 1.75m rows.

I've tried both of these MySQL import functions via command-line. **EACH time I import the same file into an empty table the Row Count is different (inconsistent)**.

1. Truncate table.
2. Import from command-line.
3. Check row count.
4. Repeat

Here are my results:

- 640,568
- 636,547
- 644,483
- 640,961

and on, and on, and on....

I've tried these two different import methods:

```
mysql -u root -ppassword --execute="USE DBNAME;LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/scripts/extracts/NAMEOFTABLE.CSV' INTO TABLE NAMEOFTABLE FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';" --show-warnings
```

output is empty, no warnings or errors (I have seen them before so I know it works)

```
mysqlimport -u root -ppassword --fields-terminated-by=, --local DBNAME /home/scripts/extracts/NAMEOFTABLE.CSV
```

This will output:
DBNAME.NAMEOFTABLE: Records: 647435  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 647435

Which at first is exciting, but then I check the rows in DB and it is only 640,480. :(

I've been at this for days. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Its  possible that if there are "comment" like fields in the data that there are embedded new-lines in that field's data that is messing things up, but weird that it is randomly(ish) inconsistent. In any case, it sounds like the data is corrupted. I would do an analysis of my data. `wc < file ; awk 'END{print "NumberOfRecs="NR}' file ; awk -F"," -v numOfCols=31 '{ if (NF != numOfCols) {print "err:" NR "found " NF " rec:" $0}' file` etc. (Of course change `31` to the correct value).  Good luck.

Comment: Doah, just noticed that your import message features `warnings: 647435`. You'll have to find out what that is about. The loader is telling you there's a problem. I would expect it is creating an error log file someplace OR that you can add an option to create such a file. OR if you're redirecting like `2>/dev/null` and not telling about it, then change to `2>./myErrorLog.txt`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks shellter but I couldn't get your first command to work. Adding 2>./myErrorlog.txt doesn't work or isn't necessary because I get the same output as running the command line. I guess the fact still remains mysql isn't printing all 647k "warnings".

Comment: Sorry, but I don't use mysql, I read your Q because it was flagged with Linux. It's hard to believe that with 42K followers for mySql that someone hasn't voluteered some more specific help. Good luck!

Comment: Ok this is insane. So I used "sed 'x-y!d' FILE>FILE2" to extract lines from my full size (647k) CSV file to test small chunks.

1-100k = success, no missing rows
1-200k = success, no missing rows
1-500k = success, no missing rows
1-600k = fail, missing rows
1-510k = success
1-525k = fail

this makes me think "the problem" happens around 510-525k. So then I do:

500k - 600k = SUCCESS

LOL what is going on?!

Comment: 150k-647k (497k rows total) = success...SIGH!!

Comment: so you don't know what caused it? Do you have tests you can run to be sure all data is in the right columns? Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query to import csv from phpmyadmin or any other mysql client

Before firing query, please make sure that table matching the fields is already created into db.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/scripts/extracts/NAMEOFTABLE.CSV' INTO TABLE `tbl_csvs`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(comma separated fields name here field1, field2, field3);
```